# +2 Rep from Edits still missing from /users/x/?tab=reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, reputation-page

The title is the question / bug report.

#### EDIT

I didn't want to personally identify a user, but it can't hurt

https://stackoverflow.com/users/614735/?tab=reputation

The user has only asked 1 question, and has suggest-edited one answer (mine).  So the calculation goes

```
1 - new
5 - question upvoted
2 - accepted answer
2 - suggested edit (approved)
```

Comment: +1 I give up—you're right.

Comment: yeah something weird is going on there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed a while back with the new design